# False positive results in email validation on mailgun

Tags: mailgun

We are doing some rather rigorous front end testing in our opt in List.

When users actually subscribed to our email list we are thinking of running email validation  (  https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-email-validation.html#email-validation ) before we even save it to the database.

Does anyone know whether this built in email validation Will result in false positive?(In other words is it possible that the function will  flag agood address as bad?)

Secondly, if we do have a false positive Address in our database: does mail gun in fact check it before trying to send it anyway. Will it get to the destination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else is searching for this....

It is highly unlikely that there will be a false positive. The APIs structure to allow permissive rather than restrictive: This means that you will not get a false positive but it's very likely that A untrue email address will be flagged as valid

Answer (score 0):

You can use MailboxValidator for a second opinion. The [demo page](http://www.mailboxvalidator.com/demo) is free and you can also sign up for the [free API plan](http://www.mailboxvalidator.com/plans#api) if you like.